# MacOS keeps reinstalling iMovie and GarageBand

Tags: macos, bug, imovie, garageband

I want to uninstall iMovie and GarageBand. But each time after I uninstall them, they are automatically reinstalled (without any message and notification). I tried to uninstall them directly (click and hold on the icon, then click on the small "x" button), or uninstall them with some other cleaner software such as App Cleaner & Uninstaller.

Anyone have similar issue like me? Is this possibly caused by the automatic updates setting?

Comment: correct, Auto updates will do that

Comment: Maybe only reinstall operation system works for me.

Comment: iMovie and GarageBand are part of the operating system

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you have guessed, the issue is with the automatic updates functionality of the App Store. To disable it, just open the App Store and (in the menu bar), go to *App Store > Settings* (or press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>). In here, just disable Automatic Updates.

[image: Screenshot (macOS Sonoma) of the App Store settings]

---

If this doesn't work, you can try disabling automatic updates (of apps in the App Store) directly in *System Settings > General > Software Update > [info button of Automatic Updates] > Install application updates from the App Store*:

[image: Screenshot (macOS Sonoma) of the Automatic Updates settings in System Settings]

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried disable all automatic staff yesterday, now I see iMovie and GarageBand again.

Comment: @Shuffle-Official Okay, I've added another solution, perhaps the apps are re-downloading each time because of updates? Keep me informed! :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I disabled all auto update staff (both in system setting and in App Store setting). I still see the apps reinstalled again. :-(

Comment: @Shuffle-Official Oh :/ Are you sure you have deleted everything related to iMovie or GarageBand on your Mac? Try searching for "iMovie" or "GarageBand" on your Mac. I can see a few files there that aren't deleting when the app is removed. Also, have a look in `~Library/Application Scripts`, `~Library/Caches`, `~Library/Preferences` and `~Library/Containers` which can contain files from the apps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Hiding the Purchase, in the App Store, under your account?

[image]

It's possible this will remove the app, without you having to turn off Automatic Updates.

Comment: Let me see if this works.

Comment: I tried hide both iMovie and GarageBand. Now I see both two softwares again. :-(